# Subclassing a type with a type parameter and replacing the type parameter with a static type in new class

Tags: c++, class, subclass, type-parameter

Say we have classes

```
class Cheese {
    string name;
};
class Wine {
    string name;
};
class Pairing: public pair {

};
```

How do we modify class `Pairing` so that T1 is always `Cheese` and T2 is always `Wine`, so that you cannot pass a type parameter to `Pairing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Cheese {
    string name;
};
class Wine {
    string name;
};
class Pairing: public pair<Cheese,Wine> {

};
```

And you might want to consider this also:

```
typedef pair<Cheese,Wine> Pairing;
```